# NDSolveValue: lost solutions?

Tags: differential-equations

Here a very easy examplary ode-problem with two solutions:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image]

as expected.

If I try to solve the same problem with NDSolveValue

```
X = NDSolveValue[{x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}] 
Plot[X[t] , {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Mathematica only evaluates one solution!!!

I'm wondering..., any idea what could be the reason? Thanks

Comment: No it's by purpose. In this way I don't have to clear x if I reevaluate NDSolveValue.

Comment: Which version are you in? In _v9.0.1_ and _v11.2_ `NDSolveValue` spits out `ndsvb` warning, and I think the warning message is quite clear. And as mentioned by J.A in the answer below, this has been mentioned in the possible issues of `NDSolveValue`, at least from _v11.2_.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, I lost my message window, so I didn't see the message(my version: 11.0.1)  I'm still wondering why NDSolveValue cannot return a list of solutions (as NDSolve can)

Comment: Try `Values@NSolve[..]`....It's not clear to me what's hard to understand about the convenience of having a call that returns a function `f` that you can apply directly to input `f[0.2]` and so forth.  You can't do that if a list of functions is returned, but have to use `Through[f[0.2]]` or some other workaround.

Comment: @ Michael E2 Thank you for your explanation! `listx=Values@NSolve[..]`  exactly returns what I would expect from `NDSolveValues`: A list of pure functions!!! The single solutions in listx can be addressed through listx[index][t]

Comment: @MichaelE2 That should be an answer (and it would justify not closing the question).

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, I guess it's hard for me to answer without thinking it through...

Answer (score 8):

[`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) is a convenience wrapper around [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve), that makes it easy to get the value of the ODE solution (an [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction) object). A simple example:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{s'[x] - s[x] == 0, s[0] == 1}, s, {x, 0, 1}]
sol[.5]
```

> [image]
>
> 1.64872

If [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) were made to return a list of multiple solutions when they exist, then the for consistency, the output should also return a list with a single solution when only one solution exists. That would mean that one would always have to do a part extraction of the result to get one of the solutions, making it far less convenient to use.

One might ask why not have just a single [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction) object (not a list) when there is only one solution, but a list of [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction) objects when there is more than one solution. That would make [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) even more inconvenient to use, as one would have to check whether the output were a list to decide if one solution or multiple solutions were returned. Even more problematic, the second argument of [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) could be a list of solutions. In that case, one would need to know the input of the [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) in order to determine whether multiple solutions or a single solution with multiple outputs were being returned.

Basically, in order to be a convenience function, [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) should only return a single solution even when multiple solutions exist. If you need to worry about multiple solutions, use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The convenience wrapper (nice wording)  `NDSolveValue` returns a single pure function. It would still remain convenient in the case of multiple solutions if `NDSolveValue` would return a list of pure functions. That's the point I'm thinking about.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann My penultimate paragraph attempts to explain why that is a bad idea (perhaps it could be worded better).

Answer (score 6):

This sort of *post hoc* reasoning behind a decision made by a group of developers is a little dangerous. I think a better phrasing of the question might be, *What are the advantages of `NDSolveValue` over `NDSolve`, given that `NDSolveValue` returns only one of the solutions computed by `NDSolve`?*  Encouraged by [@Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186556/ndsolvevalue-lost-solutions/186669#comment486198_186556) and by the upvotes on [my oversimplified comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186556/ndsolvevalue-lost-solutions/186669#comment486034_186556), here goes....

I think the primary use of `NDSolveValue` (singular, not plural `NDSolveValues`) is to return a single function `ifn` (or function expression `ifn[x]`) that can be evaluated on values of the independent variable(s).  @Carl Woll has already discussed some aspects of the convenience of this, but I would add that this use probably occurs many more times in practice than all other uses put together, because so many useful ODEs are of the form $y^{(n)} = F\big(x,y,y',\dots,y^{(n-1)}\big)$, usually just $y'=F(x,y)$ or $y''=F(x,y,y')$.  `NDSolve` will return a single solution to a valid IVP for such an ODE, and `NDSolveValue` therefore will also return the only solution.

My comment suggested that `Values@NDSolve[..]` would be equivalent to a "plural" form of `NDSolveValue`, but that's not exactly right.  `NDSolveValue` is much more general in what it can return, except that its return value will be based on the first solution returned by `NDSolve`, other solutions being ignored.  AFAICT, the following two lines are equivalent:

```
NDSolveValue[<IVP>, expr, <INTERVAL>]
expr /. First@NDSolve[<IVP>, <VARIABLES>, <INTERVAL>]
```

It seems the expression `expr` can be anything.  If `expr = 2`, then `2` is returned; if `expr = Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 10}]`, then the plot is returned, warnings aside.  As far as `Values@NDSolve[..]` goes, the equivalence limited:

```
vnds = Values@ NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1}, {x}, {t, 0, 1}];
ndsv = NDSolveValue[{x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1}, {x}, {t, 0, 1}];
First[vnds] === ndsv
(*  True  *)

vnds = Values@ NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}];
ndsv = NDSolveValue[{x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}];
First[vnds] === ndsv
First@First[vnds] === ndsv
(*
  False
  True
*)
```

They are equivalent if `expr = {x}` -- that is, if `NDSolveValue` returns the value of the list `{x}`, but not if `NDSolveValue` returns just the function `x`.

Instead of focusing on the issue of the lost solutions, one should rather think of the advantages of having some syntactic sugar equivalent to `expr /. First@NDSolve[..]`.  A couple favorites:

```
ListLinePlot@NDSolveValue[ivp, x, {t,..}]  (* equiv. to Plot[x[t], {t,..}] *)
NSolveValue[{y'[x] == f[x], y[a] == 0}, (* equiv. to NIntegrate[f[x], {x, a, b}] *)
 y[b], {x, a, b}]
```

Those are aside from the highly useful `InterpolatingFunction` returned by `NDSolveValue[ivp, x, {t, 0, 1}]`.  I think almost everyone who uses ODEs a lot hates always having to remember to type `First` in `x[t] /. First[sol]`.

OTOH, if you are analyzing a solution, I find `sol = NDSolve[ivp, x,..]` convenient for plugging into the ODE, invariants and so forth.

***Workarounds:***
*(1)*
If you want an `NDSolveValues[]` or `NDSolveValueList[]`, try this:

```
ClearAll[NDSolveValueList];
NDSolveValueList[sys_, expr_, indeps : {_, _, _} .., rest___] := 
  Module[{sol, deps},
   deps = Internal`ProcessEquations`FindDependentVariables[
     Flatten@{sys}, {indeps}[[All, 1]]];
   sol = NDSolve[sys, deps, indeps, rest];
   (expr /. sol) /; FreeQ[sol, NDSolve]
   ];
```

I don't know much about `` Internal`ProcessEquations`FindDependentVariables ``, so it might not work in all cases.  Alternatively, for non-PDE systems, one might use the following, which uses documented functions:

```
ClearAll[NDSolveValueList];
NDSolveValueList[sys_, expr_, {t_, a_, b_}, opts___?OptionQ] :=
  Module[{state, states},
   states = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[sys, expr, {t, a, b}, opts];
   Table[
       state = states[[i]];
       NDSolve`Iterate[state, {a, b}];
       First@Values@NDSolve`ProcessSolutions@state,
       {i, Length@states}] /; FreeQ[states, $Failed]
   ];
```

If there's a way to get the time-integration interval `{a, b}` from `state`, it does not seem to be documented.  If someone finds or knows it, then this could probably be extended to PDEs with ease.  The data is inside `state`.

*(2)*
If you want simply to get a different solution from `NDSolveValue`, there are two approaches.  Both determine the solution by the highest derivative value. One uses the method `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"`, and the other differentiates the ODE so that the derivative value becomes an initial condition.

```
NDSolveValue[
 {x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2,
  {x[0], x'[0]} == Values@
     Solve[{x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1} /. t -> 0, {x'[0], x[0]}][[2]]},
 x, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]

NDSolveValue[
 {D[x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2, t],
  {x[0], x'[0]} == Values@
    Solve[{x'[t]^2 == x[t]^2, x[0] == 1} /. t -> 0, {x'[0], x[0]}][[2]]},
 x, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Not related to @UlrichNeumann's original question, but I avoid `NDSolveValue` because I find it awkward to use on systems of equations.

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks for pointing that out; I agree,  I had thought of it, but for the sake of brevity left it out.  `NDSolveValue[.., {x, y},..]` is rather like the form `NDSolveValue[.., {x},..]` in which the convenience is also diminished.  And I didn't want to get into a discussion of the convenience of `{xfn, yfn,..} = NDSolveValue[.., {x, y,..},..]`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html in Possible issues/Multiple Solutions. They are indeed saying that NDSolveValue can't make it.

There are two possible differential équations in ur one : $x'(t)=x(t)$ and $x'(t)=-x(t)$.

```
X = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}] 
Plot[X[t] , {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]

X = NDSolveValue[{x'[t]== -x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}] 
Plot[X[t] , {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

will give you your two solutions

Comment: Thanks. I'm still wondering why NDSolveValue cannot return a list of solutions (as NDSolve can)